# MongoDB rename collection fails with "exceeds maximum length of 32, allowing for index names"

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

We're experiencing an issue renaming a collection in MongoDB.

The collection has some fairly long index names, but this is not an issue in the general use of the collection. We can write to it and query it, and the indexes are effective (we can tell by the drop in query performance if the indexes aren't present).

When we rename the collection however, it fails with the message below:

> MongoDB.Driver.MongoCommandException: Command 'renameCollection'
>   failed: exception: collection name length of 43 exceeds maximum length
>   of 32, allowing for index names (response: { "errmsg" : "exception:
>   collection name length of 43 exceeds maximum length of 32, allowing
>   for index names", "code" : 16451, "ok" : 0.0 })

For various reasons I won't go into here, renaming collections is an important part of our workflow.

If anyone knows of any workarounds for this issue, it'd be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Update:

Here's the DB/Collection/Index  names:

[image: Collection and index names]

Comment: Can you provide a list of your collection and index names? It looks like the code for this calculates the max collection namespace size as (120 - longestIndexLength - 1) and fails if this is exceeded. Sounds like a bug if this is not consistent with the sizing rules used for initial creation, maybe https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-7282 . Code for this check is here: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/v2.4/src/mongo/db/cloner.cpp#L864

Comment: +1 for the bug reference. Renaming doesn't work on sharded collections, btw.

Comment: What GUI tool did you get the screen shot from? it looks good :)

Comment: are you trying to rename a collection to have a longer name or is the new name the same length or shorter than the old name? If it's the same length or shorter than it may be a bug, but if longer then it makes sense that it would not be allowed if the old one was already close to the allowed length boundary.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's acceptable to have less readable index names, but you can specify the names yourself so they don't get so long(leaving more room for your collection names).

```
db.someReallyLongCollectionName.ensureIndex({
    IncludeInLocationBasedSearch: 1,
    TotalBranches: 1,
    Categories: 1
}, { name: 'short1'});
```

You could even name indexes by single characters, and have some reference for what they mean somewhere else.

That second argument `ensureIndex` takes is for options, full docs here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.ensureIndex/